# How can I send a zip file to One Drive using SSIS

Tags: ssis, onedrive

First of all, I can't use third party software, so after researching I found an easy way using "Network locations"(I use my hotmail credentials of my personal OneDrive), but I have two problems:

1. SSIS package fails when I try to send files to any folder. I get the next message:

[File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Could not find a part of the path 'X:\Documentos'.".

2. When I restart my computer I must enter my hotmail credentials again or the Network location doesn't work

Is there any solution for those problems? or maybe, Is there a better solution? thanks in advance.